# Gem found in irb, not in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have some gems installed, and I'm trying to use them in a Ruby app:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mygem'
```

When I run the app, though, I get this error: `<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require': no such file to load -- mygem (LoadError)`

But if I try requiring the gem inside `irb` (making sure to `require 'rubygems' first), it works fine. What am I supposed to do? I tried googling for this problem, but didn't understand.

Running a `which` on `ruby`, `gem`, and `irb` shows that they're all in `/opt/local/bin/`, i.e.,

```
> which ruby
/opt/local/bin/ruby
> which gem
/opt/local/bin/gem
> which irb
/opt/local/bin/irb
```

Update to answer  the questions posed (yep, irb and ruby are pointing to different folders):

`$LOAD_PATH` and `$:` in irb both contain seem to be pointing to ruby 1.8 folders:

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8
/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10
/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10
.
```

`$:` in ruby points to ruby 1.9.1 folders:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i386-darwin9.8.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i386-darwin9.8.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-darwin9.8.0
```

`gem env` shows

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.4.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-darwin10]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gempath" => ["/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"]
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/", "http://gems.github.com", "http://gems.github.com"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
     - http://gems.github.com
     - http://gems.github.com
```

`Gem.path` in irb points to

```
/Users/grautur/.gem/ruby/1.8
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

`Gem.path` in ruby points to

```
/Users/grautur/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
```

Comment: What do your `$LOAD_PATH` or `$:` variables contain? Examining those in each environment will probably be fairly informative.

Comment: Hmm, irb seems to be using ruby 1.8 (`$LOAD_PATH` and `$:` are both /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8,/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10,/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby,/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8,/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10,/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby,/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8,/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10,.), while ruby is using ruby 1.9.1 (`$LOAD_PATH` is empty, `$:` is the 1.9.1 versions of the previous paths).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's going on. However, the following may help.

In irb, do

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mygem'
puts $:
```

and then, in ruby, do

```
require 'rubygems'
puts $:
```

and show us what you get if you haven't worked it out.

**Edit:** also print out the results of doing `gem env` on the command line.

**Edit 2:** See what happens if you type in `puts Gem.path` after you've required rubygems in both irb and ruby. See [thanks to Matt for describing Rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181684/how-does-require-rubygems-help-find-rubygem-files/6182387#6182387)

Comment: Hmm, yep, ruby and irb seem to be using different paths (ruby is using 1.9.1 folders, and irb is using 1.8 folders). Do you know how I get them to use the same path?

Comment: @grautur: I don't know what to do. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to add `gem 'mygem'` before the require, but that should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add `gem install mygem` in your Gamefile and then run `bundle install` command. Your application will work correctly after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I had [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344451/ruby-require-problem-something-to-do-with-load-path/6353129#6353129). The solution I found eventually was to setup [rvm](https://rvm.io) (ruby version manager) on my system and use it to setup a new ruby environment. it also makes it easy to switch between ruby versions of sets of gems.