# Cannot require Ruby module

Tags: ruby

When executing the file "dbTest.rb" :

```
require 'mysql'
con = Mysql::new("192.168.10.70", "dbuser", "asd1234", "asd")
puts con.get_server_info
```

By :

```
ruby dbTest.rb
```

I get the error :

```
dbTest.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- mysql (LoadError)
```

When I execute "gem list" , I see mysql, mysql2 and dbd-mysql all there.
Can you point out my error ? Thx in advance for your time.

Cheers !

Edit :

For the reasons that are unknown to me I have two 1.8 versions but the gem is talking to the right ruby :

```
cem@skynet:/usr/bin$ sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
[sudo] password for cem: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative ruby (providing /usr/bin/ruby).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/ruby1.8     50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/ruby1.8     50        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1   10        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
cem@skynet:/usr/bin$ sudo update-alternatives --config gem
There are 2 choices for the alternative gem (providing /usr/bin/gem).

  Selection    Path               Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/gem1.8     180       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gem1.8     180       manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/gem1.9.1   10        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Comment: Since you are using a older version of ruby, you might want to check to see that the version of mysql gem is combatiable with the version of ruby you are trying to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using Ruby 1.8 I believe `require 'rubygems'` is required:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'
con = Mysql::new("192.168.10.70", "dbuser", "asd1234", "asd")
puts con.get_server_info
```

If you wish to know more, checkout the answer at "[How does require rubygems help find rubygem files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181684/how-does-require-rubygems-help-find-rubygem-files)".

Comment: I'm new to ruby can you also tell me why ?

Comment: added a link to the answer with full explanation in it